# If X is a nonnegative random variable, $\mathbb{E}\left[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X\geq t\}}\right]\leq\mathbb{E}[X]$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, then
> $$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X\geq t\}}\right]\leq\mathbb{E}[X].$$

What is the formal proof of the above statement? I can see how this can be true but I am not sure how to formally write this. I saw this being used in the proof of Markov's inequality.

Comment: $Y:=X-X\mathbf 1_A$ is a nonnegative r.v. (for any event $A$). And $\mathbb E\,Y\ge0$ for any nonnegative r.v. $Y$.

Comment: Use $X \,\ \textbf{1}\{X \geq t\}\leq X$?

Comment: Consider this, when $X$ is non-negative, then $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X1_{\{X\ge0\}}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: this is equivalent to showing $\mathbb{E}[Y] \ge 0$, where $Y$ is the following random variable:

$$Y \doteq X - X \times 1_{X \ge t} = X\times(1 - 1_{X \ge t})=X \times 1_{X < t}.$$

[Note that $1-1_{X \ge t}$ is nonnegative everywhere; it is $1$ when $X$ is less than $t$ and $0$ otherwise. [In fact, $1-1_{X \ge x}$ is precisely $1_{X < t}$.]]

Can you finish from here. What can we say about the product of two random variables $X$ and $1_{X < t}$ that are each nonnegative everywhere.